# request and respond in function. Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

If I change position of req with res for example (res,req)=>{ res.send();}
the server shows error that res.send is not a function.
My question is are we restricted with positioning the req,res objects?
why it throws the error the res.send() is not a function or why is it trying to see it as a function?

Comment: Just because you name the variables something other than what they are doesn't mean that they will just magically become what you name them. Arguments are passed positionally; it's on you to name them in your callback.

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Comment: The names of your arguments can be anything you want them to be.  What matters is the position.  The first argument will be the `request` object and the second argument will be the `response` object regardless of what names you give them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(res,req) => {res.send();}
```

is a function with two parameters. When it is invoked by the express framework, the first will be passed a request object (which has no `.send` function) and the second will be passed a response object (which has a `.send` function). Your code wants to invoke the `.send` function of the first object (which you misleadingly call `res`), but that first object is a request and has no `.send` function.

See the express API documentation [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the variable name, can push new variables to request but you can not change functionality of internal request and response object. And as per request functionality , it accepts what you send in request and Send() is not part of request.